# Short duration change background image on mouseover

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, background-image, mouseover

I want to go one step further in making a web page background image change on mouseover of an object on that page. I would like the replacement image to last just a fraction of a second before immediately reverting to the original. On top of that I would like to play a short sound file.

To put this request in context: I am preparing a website with a photographic theme. The original background image will be dark and will be of a photographer with a camera. When an object is moused over, the replacement image will be the same except for a bright (solid white) area over the camera. This is to represent a flashgun firing. Hence the sound file also.

I am quite happy to mix javascript,JQuery and CSS.

Is this possible??

TIA

Brian

Comment: Can you give us some code?

Comment: Don't use mouseover, use mouseenter event

Answer (score 1):

Here is the **[working demo](https://jsfiddle.net/yxdegq2w/)** of what I did.

I have used the mouseover event,

```
$("#img").on("mouseover",function(){

        //code to display the image for fraction of second
        $("#img").fadeTo(1,1);
        $("#img").fadeTo(300,0.4);

    });
```

Where `img` is the id of the image. To increase/decrease the duration of the image to stay clear you can alter the value 300.

To add a gunshot audio you can write the below code within the above `mouseover` event,

```
//code to play the gunshot
        var audioElement = document.createElement('audio');
        audioElement.setAttribute('src', 'gunshot.mp3');
        audioElement.setAttribute('autoplay', 'autoplay');
        //audioElement.load()

        $.get();

        audioElement.addEventListener("load", function() {
            audioElement.play();
        }, true);

        $('.play').click(function() {
            audioElement.play();
        });
```